# Altium Convert .PrjPcb to .PrjMbd - Single Board to Multiple Board?

Tags: pcb, schematics, altium, microprocessor, converter

I started my project single PCB board. But now, I need multiple boards for this project.

How can I convert my file format? How can I convert my Schematic Diagrams for multiple board project? How can I convert .PrjPcb to .PrjMbd?

Comment: If you right-click the project in the projects panel, select "Add new to project" and select "PCB" what happens? I have multiple PCBs in a project while the project file itself remains just a `.PrjPcb`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. In the link I mentioned below is help me about this topic.

Thank you for your interest.

https://resources.altium.com/p/multi-board-design-projects-in-altium-designer

Answer (score 0):

There is no such conversion, because the two file types are different things. The PrjPCB is still used for the traditional Schematics/Layout design flow for each of your multiple boards.

Afterwards, you create a multi-board project (PrjMbd) and add your already existing single-board projects to it. The PrjMbd contains yet another schematics page, connecting the individual schematics together and allows to assemble the individual PCBs into one assembly.

I guess you are looking for a concept that uses one set of schematics and has this placed on separate PCBs. This is a feature that doesn't exist in Altium.